# Where is from "ERROR: Spider error processing <GET..." in scrapy?

Tags: python, logging, scrapy, error-logging

I am reading a log from a previous spider's launching. I am curious to know where is from this exception and how I can act on it:

```
2019-04-12 22:00:55 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.website.com/next_page> (referer: https://www.website.com/prev_page)
Traceback (most recent call last):...
```

I looked at the files `middlewares.py`, `settings.py` and so on in my project and I do not find any lines where it is written `logging.error` or `spider.logger.error`. Even in the built-in methods `def process_spider_exception(self, response, exception, spider):` or `def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):` I do not find any line that orders a log message. Looking at the documentation does not clarify it, as for me.

Now about to act on it. If I would like to know where it is from, is because I would like to try to insert some lines that orders to add the urls in a file dedicated to some kind of exceptions that make rise an spider error processing to analyze it, correct it, and launch the spider again on these specific urls from this file because that's more comfortable than from a scrapy log file.

Beyond the wish of acting on it, I would like to know where it is and how it works.

Comment: Without full log message it is pretty hard understand what kind of exception did you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, that log messsage is coming from handle_spider_error method in scrapy package

[core/scraper.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/b5c552d17ff9e9629434712c3d0595c02853bcfc/scrapy/core/scraper.py)

Regarding finding source of error, hints are usually traceback that comes along with this error log.

You can also follow code that call this url 'https://www.website.com/next_page'

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly from it, no doubt. And I see that's not a good idea to write in it as it is made. I gonna search how to answer this problematic.